# CAKeyframeAnimation counter-clockwise

Tags: ios, swift2, cakeyframeanimation

I want to animate along a bezierPath counter-clockwise.

At the moment the code below only allows me to do it clockwise.

```
        let arrowHead = UIImageView()
        arrowHead.image = UIImage(named: "arrowHead.png")
        arrowHead.frame = CGRect(x: 55, y: 300, width: 12, height: 12)


        let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(50, 240, 320, 240))
        let ovalShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        ovalShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        ovalShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        ovalShapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.5
        ovalShapeLayer.path = ovalPath.CGPath


        self.view.layer.addSublayer(ovalShapeLayer)

        let myKeyFrameAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        myKeyFrameAnimation.path = ovalPath.CGPath

        myKeyFrameAnimation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
        myKeyFrameAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        myKeyFrameAnimation.duration = 6.0

        // add the animation
        arrowHead.layer.addAnimation(myKeyFrameAnimation, forKey: "animate position along path")
        self.view.addSubview(arrowHead)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok got it.

`myKeyFrameAnimation.speed = -1`

Was very simple...

Answer (score 0):

At alternative solution is to use `bezierPathWithArcCenter...` as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:) which allows you to specify the direction of the circle. Using `-M_PI_2` as the start angle and `3 * M_PI_2` as the end angle will give a circle beginning and ending at the top.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know how you can have continuous movement? At moment the animation repeats infinitely BUT there is a short split second of pause while the new animation restarts after previous ended.

Comment: If you make the path above, you probably need to close it.

Comment: "Above" as in your answer or mine?

Comment: my answer, sorry. And you will probably want to make sure the timing function is linear for the animation, or you'll notice acceleration and deceleration at the loop point.